# Changing state in Redux based on previous state

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am struggling a bit with Redux.

While I have managed to move some very simple states to Redux based on tutorials, I find it difficult to deal with more complex ones. Tried researching but answers vary and confuse.

The way I understand it,  the equivalent of setState lies in Redux's actions and should be achieved by using  getState() and then bt dispatch()ing  the action to reducer...

If yes, then how to correctly translate the below example into Redux?

Let's say toggling a boolean of some nested music state element:

```
  this.setState(prevState => {
    const updatedMusic = prevState.music;
    const elToUpdate = updatedMusic.musicStateItemList[3].favClicked;
    elToUpdate = !elToUpdate;
    return {
      music: updatedMusic
    };
  });
```

Comment: Can you post the redux examples you have tried to translate so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the equivalent with your sample code in Redux is as below

```
const updatedMusic = state.music;
const elToUpdate = updatedMusic.musicStateItemList[3].favClicked;
updatedMusic.musicStateItemList[3].favClicked = !elToUpdate;
return {
  ...state,
  music: [...updatedMusic]
};
```

it is about mutating state. You can use immutability helper if you want more advanced.

Answer (score 0):

In the reducer the state is passed

```
function counter(state = 0, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'INCREMENT':
      return state + 1
    case 'DECREMENT':
      return state - 1
    default:
      return state
  }
}

let store = createStore(counter)
```

From the docs: https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started